VBScript, how to put a dictionay inside another dictionary using .Item setter?
A.S. this is NOT dup: How can I use a dictionary inside a class in vbscript?

i do NOT want to make new classes
i also do not want to make ad hoc wrappers (would i - i would just use array(1) instead of ad hoc classes)


sub Test()
  Dim D, V  ' "as Variant" - not supported in VBS
  Set D = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  D.Item("ffff") = 12345
  DlgOk "set_item (int) ok"
  Set V = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  D.Add "sdfsdfs", V
  DlgOk "add (dict) ok"
  D.Item("sdfsdfs") = V
  DlgOk "set_item ok"
end sub

DlgOk is merely out internal function to show a modal window.
According to the latest WSH 5.6 documentation this all should work, except it does not.
With simple values - D.Item("ffff") = 12345 it works like a charm.
An explicit dunction call - D.Add "sdfsdfs", V - works okay too, and in specific workflows where the outer dictionary is warranted to be empty can be used.
However the D.Item("sdfsdfs") = V line would fail (regardless whether there is or is not .Add call above). And i can not "just replace" the .Set_Item with .Add everywhere, because the latter would fail if the value already existed.
The failure is the infamous error 01C2 / 800A01C2 / ...invalid property assignment.
The COM declaration (can be checked in the ObjView) is rather exotic:
[id(00000000), propputref, helpstring("Set or get the item for a given key"), helpcontext(0x00214b3a)]
HRESULT Item(
                [in] VARIANT* Key, 
                [in] VARIANT* pRetItem);

[id(00000000), propput, helpstring("Set or get the item for a given key"), helpcontext(0x00214b3a)]
HRESULT Item(
                [in] VARIANT* Key, 
                [in] VARIANT* pRetItem);

[id(00000000), propget, helpstring("Set or get the item for a given key"), helpcontext(0x00214b3a)]
HRESULT Item(
                [in] VARIANT* Key, 
                [out, retval] VARIANT* pRetItem);

It seems those two almost identical setters drive many language runtimes crazy, INCLUDING the VBScript which was released in that very same package, anytime you try to put some iDispatch/object there, while plain values like integer or array work everywhere.
I can imagine all kinds of workarounds with if-ladders there, but... maybe i am missing something trivial and one can make immediate .Item assignments work with objects?

It's an object reference so you need Set, try Set D.Item("sdfsdfs") = V instead.

@user692942  oooops, silly me. Still can't make it work without huge scaffolding in "traditional" natively compiled languages, but as for VBS itself your answer is correct. Hope they would let you make it an answer

It’s fine, it’s been answered many times before. The duplicate explains how object references require Set when assigning them to variables. This was the problem you were having.
